# C# System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure keep coming up “System.ExecutionEngineException” error message

Tags: c#

```
Node
{
  public object key;
  public object value;
}

int[] cache = new int[200*8];
int[] PtrList = new int[200];
int m_node_length = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Node));

fixed (byte* array = m_cache)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < PtrList.Length; i++)
        PtrList[i] = (int)new IntPtr(array + i * (m_node_length));
}
```

I initialize data as above content.Then I use "Marshal.StructureToPtr" to store data：

```
Node n = new Node();
n.key = a // a is int number
n.value = b // b is int number
IntPtr p = (IntPtr)PtrList[X]; // X >= 0 & X < 200
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(n, p, true);
```

And when I use "System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure" ,sometimes (not all) get the error message:

```
The exception of the "System.ExecutionEngineException" type is not handled in the mscorlib.dll
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's not clear where are you getting the error, at StructureToPtr or PtrToStructure?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using PtrToStructure() doing the reverse, i.e. marshaling data from unmanaged to managed.